# Ignoring funny ref

Tags: git, dropbox

```
git version 1.7.7
```

I have dropbox git repository.

From my works computer `karl-sun` I have push my branches to my dropbox.

When I get home on my home computer `karl-net` I fetch my latest changes, do some more work and then push to my dropbox.

When I do this I get the following messages.

```
error: * Ignoring funny ref 'refs/remotes/origin/dev (karl-sun's conflicted copy 2011-09-07)' locally
```

This is annoying is there any way I can get rid of it. And why does it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [this blog post](https://shiki.me/blog/ignoring-funny-ref-error-on-git-dropbox)

> It seems to happen when 2 people push to origin/master at almost the
>   same time. This makes Dropbox update the same file and seems to be the
>   cause of the error. When this happens, you can bet that one of the
>   people who did the push will lose his changes to origin/master. So
>   you’ll have to fix it accordingly.
>
> The “funny ref” error does not have any critical effect on the repo
>   and Git seems to work perfectly. It will just annoy you every time you
>   try to fetch. It turns out that this "master (Shiki's conflicted copy
>   2010-01-14)" is a branch in the main repo. Simply deleting it will
>   remove the error. In terminal, go to your main repo’s (Dropbox) root
>   folder:
>
> `git branch -d "master (Shiki's conflicted copy 2010-01-14)"`